# Notepad++ special string character highlighting

Tags: printf, notepad++, highlighting

In notepad++ if I have the code

```
 printf("Hello, World\n");
```

The whole string '"Hello, World\n"' is one color but in editors like vim '\n' is a different color signifying it's a special character. Is there to get this behavior in notepad++? It's an especially nice feature of vim to highlight some of the stranger printf syntax like '% 5.3s' or '%%'

Comment: You switched _from_ vim _to_ Notepad++?

Comment: you mentioned vim, referenced vim feature, but the question has nothing to do with vim, hasn't it? I feel the `vim` tag could be removed. what do u think?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin could be, because vim is just too productive, boss keeps giving him new tasks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind editing some xml, I'm sure you could make the appropriate settings in `stylers.xml` where all syntax highlighting settings for Notepad++ are saved. It is usually located in `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\`

Here is the wiki:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Editing_Configuration_Files

Otherwise, you could try to find a theme online and import it with `settings->import->import theme`